# Data doesn't change after sending PUT method

Tags: python, django

I'm doing some basic CRUD application with python django. Basicly, from the Front End, I want to send some raw text data, the Backend will catch It, and re-send the cleaned ones.
For now, the clean method worked but for some reason, It still sending the same raw text to the Front End.

This is my code:

in models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(max_length=3000, blank=False, default='')
```

in serializers.py:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ('id', 'content')
```

in views.py:

```
@api_view(['PUT'])
def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        post_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        post_serializer = PostSerializer(data = post_data)
        if post_serializer.is_valid():
            data_to_clean= str(post_serializer.data['content']) # this is raw text (i.e: "aBcD")
            cleaned = clean(data_to_clean) # this is text after cleaning (i.e: "abcd")
            post_serializer.data['content'] = cleaned # update the new text
            return JsonResponse(post_serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return JsonResponse(post_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Can you point out what is wrong with this code. Many thanks.

Comment: I guess you need to call `post_serializer.update()`

Answer (score 1):

post_serializer is immutable you cannot change that You have to create the exact copy of that and you can do your operation

```
from django.http import QueryDict
@api_view(['PUT'])
def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        post_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        post_serializer = PostSerializer(data = post_data)
        if post_serializer.is_valid():
            data_to_clean= str(post_serializer.data['content']) # this is raw text (i.e: "aBcD")
            cleaned = clean(data_to_clean) # this is text after cleaning (i.e: "abcd")
            query_dict = QueryDict('', mutable=True)
            query_dict.update(post_serializer.data)
            query_dict.data['content'] = cleaned # update the new text
            return JsonResponse(query_dict.data, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return JsonResponse(query_dict.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will give It a try as soon as possible

Comment: Hi suresh, I tried your code but It seems like QueryDict object doesn't have attribute 'data'

Comment: I found it! If we just type "query_dict['content'] =... ", It will work like a charm. Thanks for your help